# Dynamic Alert Capture in web driver selenium

Tags: java, validation, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to selenium scripts and I need to capture the dynamic alerts displayed in the form for field validation ,currently i can capture the  static alerts displayed for field validation, can u guys help me out of this.

Comment: What exactly u mean dynamic alerts? Do you mean alert pop ups is displayed dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

```
 driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```